# Fundamental group of twice punctured torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need to calculate $\pi_1 (T \setminus \{P_1, P_2\})$ where $T$ is the two-dimensional torus, and $P_1, P_2$ are any two points. So I need to calculate the fundamental group of the twice punctured torus. I don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: How did you compute the fundamental group of the once-punctured torus?

Comment: Hint: the torus with one point removed is homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of two circles.

Comment: I found a deformation retract from $I^2 \setminus P \rightarrow \delta I^2$ to calculate it for the once-punctured torus.

Comment: Can't you find a subspace of $I^2$ to which the complement of two points deformation retracts?

Answer (score 1):

First note that $T\setminus \{P_1, P_2\}$ deformation retracts to the union of three copies of $S^1$ touching pairwise, which is homeomorphic to $\bigvee^3_{i=1}S^1$.

So $T \setminus \{P_1, P_2\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee^3_{i=1}S^1$, which implies that $$\pi_1(T \setminus\{P_1, P_2\}) \cong \pi_1\Bigg(\bigvee^3_{i=1}S^1\Bigg) \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}.$$ (You can prove the isomorphism via Van Kampen's Theorem.)